# Is there any way to get a hook or event in Electron JS when a new application is launched

Tags: node.js, electron, cross-platform

I'm new to Electron JS. Trying to build a cross-platform desktop application to watch user activities.

My requirement is when a user moves out of my application and opens some other application like a browser/ calculator, is there any way that can be monitored from my application?

Please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this electron api:

```
let spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

let bat = spawn("cmd.exe", [
    "/c",          // Argument for cmd.exe to carry out the specified script
    "D:\test.bat", // Path to your file
    "argument1"   // Optional first argument
]);

bat.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    // Handle data...
});

bat.stderr.on("data", (err) => {
    // Handle error...
});

bat.on("exit", (code) => {
    // Handle exit
});
```

Make sure to put the correct path to your batch file (here is an example to find notepad):

```
tasklist | find /i "notepad.exe" && echo true || echo false
```

Make sure to handle only false, because true will log notepad.exe info, too.

**P.S.: The batch script works only for Windows, I don't know how to create the bash version.**